# Can I work around "rebuilding" to load the debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm running vs08 in xp trying to test a c++ solution that I've been working on for some time.

The solution consists of several projects, two of which I'm working on contain a server and client respectively. I build debug instances of both server and client projects to test custom messages sent between them.

The debugger has only been able to load the debug information for an edited header file (using mostly templates) if I "rebuild" (clean + build) the entire project, instead of just "building". If I try to "build" then debug the project, all my break points in the header file are not accessible and I get a warning that:

> "This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is
>   associated with this line."

However, if I "rebuild" the entire project, the debugger works.

I've looked in "Solution properties > Common Properties > Debug Source Files" and made sure that the "Do not look for these source files" section is blank.

I'd like to just "build" each project (a much shorter operation between small code changes) to debug. (1) What setting in visual studio can I change?

Note that I'm using "build" and "rebuild" in reference to the features in visual studio. My understanding of these is that "rebuild" deletes the .pdb (program debug database) and associated debug files, then generates the needed files, while "build" only modifies the debug files that correlate to new code changes. (2) Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Visual Studio, but the cause to your problem is most likely because that specific source file is not rebuilt during the compilation.
If you haven't made any changes to the source file you have just added a break point to since the last time you built the project, it will not get rebuilt this time around.

Rebuild works because it cleans all the object files and then build the project from scratch.

To work around, you can try either modifying the source file you specifically want to rebuild, or just delete its object file from the build directory.

Comment: Thanks. When I edit code in one file then "build", the breakpoints in that file stop working until I "rebuild". I can't seem to find an object file - I would assume it's because the file I'm editing is a header-only file that uses mostly templates, so there isn't an object?

Comment: If you modify a header file, then VS should be smart enough to rebuild all the related files (source files that include that header). But I also remember reading on SO about something that visual studio can sometimes mess up about time stamps on files and not build properly.